# Why does C# MongoDB 2.19 upgrade throw InvalidCastException even though class maps are registered

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

We have a series of microservices that are back by MongoDB, all was working until we upgraded to version 2.19, now they all break and no tests will pass.

The ObjectSerializer breaking change is causing a lot of issues in our codebase, our preference is not to have to rollback the version, but have been unable to fix this issue without having to duplicate the ClassMaps by registering custom serializers for every entity.

The suggested fix:

```
var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
```

Does not work for us as it throws a duplicate error for the default object serializer.

All our classes match the [available guides](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/class-mapping/).

Is there a way to update our code without having a write custom serializers in addition to the ClassMaps for every entity?

Comment: ` a duplicate error for the default object serializer` - it looks like this happens because of your side configuration, you should provide details about it to better understand your issue

Comment: I think I will need to try and make a simple POC for this issue. it will be easier than trying to explain it all, and will hopefully help me debug.